# Endless for loop with float

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, increment

Consider the following code:

```
for (float i = 0f; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    // Some code
}
```

Which is supposed to loop from `0` to `int.MaxValue` (2<sup>31</sup>-1), but it doesn't. Once `i` reached 2<sup>24</sup>, `i++` doesn't work anymore for a reason that I'm totally unable to understand.

In the Immediate Window of VS I've try this:

```
>i
16777216.0
>i + 1
16777216.0 // ???
>i == i + 1
false // as expected, but a lack of consistency with upper statement
>i + 2
16777218.0
```

Why does it behave like so? What is special with 2<sup>24</sup>+1?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is because of float precision. It is based on IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)). Read it to understand how floating point works.

In simple words when a float stores a large value in itself; the difference between currently stored number and the next number it can store, is larger than 1 so adding 1 to it does not increase it's value.

If you need exact decimal number use [decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) instead.
If you need integral value larger than int then use [long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx).
If you need very large integral values then use [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).