# Is maximum float + x defined behavior?

Tags: c++, hlsl

I did a quick test using the following:

```
float x = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
x += 0.1;
```

that resulted in x == std::numeric_limits::max() so it didn't get any bigger than the limit.

Is this guaranteed behavior across compilers and platforms though? What about HLSL?

Comment: See [my question about float precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444413/endless-for-loop-with-float)

Comment: Try `x + 0.1 * x` instead. 0.1 is negligible when added to very large numbers, but you can always meaningfully add one tenth of a number (unless you're dealing with numbers that are reeeaaally close to zero).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this guaranteed behavior across compilers and platforms though?

No, the behavior is undefined. The standard says (emphasis mine):

> **5 Expressions**
> ....
>   If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
>   representable values for its type, ***the behavior is undefined***. [ *Note*: most existing implementations of C++
>   ignore integer overflows. Treatment of division by zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and ***all
>   floating point exceptions vary among machines***, and is usually adjustable by a library function. —*end note* ]

As **@user2079303** mentioned, in  practice we can be less restricted:

> it is ***not undefined if*** `std::numeric_limits<float>::has_infinity`. Which is often true. In that case, the result is ***merely unspecified***.

Comment: *or not in the range of representable values for its type* => I'm not sure it's out of range since the addition can't be done due to lack of precision...

Comment: @ThomasAyoub In any case the standard does not specify floating point representation, it does not have to be IEEE. So perhaps we should not make assumptions on precision.

Comment: Actually, it is not undefined if `std::numeric_limits<float>::has_infinity`. Which is often true. In that case, the result is merely unspecified.

Comment: @user2079303 Thanks! Do you mind that I added it to my post?

Comment: @AlexD I don't mind at all. In fact, I do prefer your answer to be more complete. Feel free to have added it.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is defined to be the maximum finite value representable by type `T` (see 18.3.2.4 [numeric.limits.members] paragraph 4). Thus, the question actually becomes multiple subquestions:

1. Is it possible to create a value bigger than `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`, i.e., is there an infinity?
2. If so, which value needs to be added to `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` to get the infinity?
3. If not, is the behavior defined?

C++ does not specify the floating point format and different formats may disagree on what the result is. In particular, I don't think floating point formats need to define a value for infinity. For example, [IBM Floating Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Floating_Point_Architecture) do not have an infinity. On the other hand the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) does have an infinity representation.

Since overflow of arithmetic types may be undefined behavior (see 5 [expr] paragraph 4) and I don't see any exclusion for floating point types. Thus, the behavior would be undefined behavior if there is no infinity. At least, it can be tested whether a type does have an infinity (see 18.3.2.3 [numeric.limits] paragraph 35) in which case the operation can't overflow.

If there is an infinity I *think* adding any value to `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` would get you infinity. However, determining whether that is, indeed, the case would require to dig through the respective floating point specification. I could imagine that IEEE 754 might ignore additions if the value is too small to be relevant as is the case for adding `0.1` to `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`. I could also imagine that it decides that it always overflows to infinity.